# Using scale_x_continuous in ggplot with x and y axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with the x and y axis limited with scale_x_continuous. However, I also want to add x and y axis labels. This brings up this message:

Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.

I have also tried ylab = and xlab = in the + labs 'section' but it also produced the same error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. This is my script:

```
MigrPlt = ggplot(Migr,aes(Distance3, `newBa`))+
geom_line()+
scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+ 
xlim(0, 3800)+ 
ylim(0,25) + 
labs(y= expression (paste('Ba:Ca (µmol mol'^~-1,')')), x = "Distance from Core (μm)") + 
geom_hline(yintercept=2.25, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+ 
geom_vline(xintercept = 1193.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey")+ 
geom_vline(xintercept = 1965.5, linetype="dashed", color = "grey") + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 2616.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey") + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 3202.8, linetype="dashed", color = "grey")+ 
geom_vline(xintercept = 3698.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlim` is a shortcut to the `limits` term of `scale_x_XXXX`, and it will overwrite any prior x scale settings. If you want to control the range of the x data, and the number of breaks, put both inside `scale_x_continuous`.

You might also consider using `coord_cartesian()` to control the axes -- the main difference is that it will keep all the input data, whereas using `xlim` or `scale_x_continuous(limits =`  will filter out any data outside the specified range before it gets used by any geoms. This often surprises users who are using `geom_smooth` or `geom_box` or other summarizing geoms.

Compare:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10) +
  xlim(0, 10)
  # Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Jon. Just to clarify, would it now look like this for both x and y limits:  + scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+ limits(0, 7500)+ scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+ limits (0,25)

Comment: When I ran it this way I received the following error: Error in limits(0, 7500) : could not find function "limits"

Comment: This also produced the same error: scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits(0, 7500)) + scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits (0,25))

Comment: Please see the syntax in the answer above. `limits` is a parameter inside the `scale_x_continuous` function, and you set it with `limits = c(MIN, MAX)`.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Thanks to [Jon Spring's direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69803844/3025856), I've got the answer! The correction for the section is as follows:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 7500))+ scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0,25))
```